# ASP.net dont fire unload on normal postback

Tags: asp.net, session

If I leave my current page on a asp.net Web application I want that all sessions get destroyed. For that I am using `Session.Abandon()` on `Page_Unload` Event. But if I do a Postback with a normal Button_Click I don't want to fire this event.

It would be awesome if you could help me.

Lingo

Comment: put your some code here.

Comment: Page_Unload is part or the Page life cycle in .Net. It will raise after every postback. I think you should be destroying the session before redirecting to the next page

Comment: @ Emi1305 So I have to Destroy my sessions on each menu item click? Is there an event which is fired on each redirect?

Comment: @Lingo No, there is no event on redirect. I don't know your particular case but I doubt you might destroy your sessions on each click. I think you have some code like this:

destroySession();
Server.Transfer(/*Next page here*/...);

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand how the web works. When you access stackoverflow.com for example your are actualy seeing the past. The page you accessed it's already destroyed on the web server.

Based on that principle when you use Page_Unload or Session.Abandon if you actually close your browser you don't send any request for the web server so the web server didn't know (and don't care even) if you close your page.

For doing like

```
The page unload description act like this it's after being rendered it's had nothing with the close of the page.


"The Unload event is raised after the page has been fully rendered, sent to the client, and is ready to be discarded. 
At this point, page properties such as Response and Request are unloaded and cleanup is performed.'
```

Reference (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)

You need to use javascript for doing this behaviour or try the new websocket that will keep the connection alive and the server could check if the client has lost the link with the server.